# Parsing through json file using python

Tags: python, json, api

I am using the OpenWeatherMap API in building a slack bot feature in which user can enter the name of the city and the current weather forecast will be shown.

But the API uses unique city id's to match the corresponding city name which are json objects.

Some lines of the json file are like this-

```
[
  {
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.283333,
      "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 519188,
    "name": "Novinki",
    "country": "RU",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.666668,
      "lat": 55.683334
    }
  },
]
```

I want to match the city name entered by the user with its corresponding city id by searching through the json file and matching the correct city name and fetching the corresponding city id, which will be sent in the API call as is required by the API to process.

How to achieve this thing in python?

Answer (score 0):

try if this helps:

```
jsonobject = [
  {
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.283333,
      "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 519188,
    "name": "Novinki",
    "country": "RU",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.666668,
      "lat": 55.683334
    }
  },
]

for elem in jsonobject:
  print (elem['id'])
```

Output:

```
707860
519188
```

Comment: See the json file contains thousands of objects similar to these two, so iterating through the entire file to search for let's say, the last object will be very time consuming and inefficient. Isn't there an efficient or better way to do this?

Comment: Am not sure if there is any other way with out iterating through all 'id'. But I guess my answer pointed out a way to extract id from json object as per your question. We can wait if some one has better solution.

Comment: If I name it jsonobject = [ ... ] then it's showing an error Parse error on line 1:
jsonobject = [ {
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: please post code and error you are getting, was not able to figure out what you meant by your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of the solution:

```
city_name = 'Novinki'

for city in jsonobject:
    if city['name'] == city_name:
        print(city['id'])
```

I believe that you have dictionary in your example and not json (probably you have already parsed it).